# Passing NSManagedObjectContext reference when using StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, core-data, uistoryboard

I was looking at the Pro Core Data examples and I was wondering what a good way to pass around the ManagedObjectContext is.  In the examples in the book, I see the author initialize the ManagedObjectContext in the AppDelegate, then he does this in MasterViewController

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"League Manager", @"League Manager");
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then when a new ViewController is pushed on the stack from a table row selection, this is done:

```
NSManagedObject *team = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  TeamViewController *teamViewController = [[TeamViewController alloc] initWithMasterController:self team:team];
  [self presentModalViewController:teamViewController animated:YES];
```

Using StoryBoards, I don't see that type of init method anymore.  I see the prepareForSegue is mainly used and I see in the Beginning iOS 5 Development book, the author would do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        UIViewController *destination = ((UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController).topViewController;

        if ([destination  respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
            [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];
        }
```

I can't figure out a good way to keep my classes decoupled and have a reference to the managedObjectContext in my viewControllers.  Do I have a managedObjectContext that I just set on all my view controllers that need to see it?  Do I do what the author in the first example did and keep a reference to the MasterViewController that has the reference and pass that around to my different ViewControllers?  I'm not sure what is "best practices" for something like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prepareForSegue:sender:` is indeed the preferred way to pass data from one view controller to another when using storyboards.  The example prepareForSegue code you posted is exactly how you'd do it.  I have exactly this code in one of my apps:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showLog"] ) {
        UIViewController* logView = segue.destinationViewController;
        if( [logView respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)] ) {
            [logView setValue:self.managedObjectContext forKey:@"managedObjectContext"];
        }
    }
}
```

The [Storyboard session from last year's WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#introducing-interface-builder-storyboarding) is good watching, if you haven't seen it.